# Time to return to initial position given $v(t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, kinematics

**Question:**

A particle moves in a straight line such that its velocity, $v$ in m/s, at time $t$ seconds, is given by:

$$v(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 5-(t-2)^2, & 0\leq t\leq 4\\ 3-\frac{t}{2},& t>4\end{array}\right.$$

the particle returns to its initial position at $t=T$. Find the value of $T$.

**Doubt/Problem:**

The mark scheme suggests that the initial position is equal to the distance travelled before coming to rest. Whereas I believe the initial position is the displacement at $t=0$, which I found out to be $4.33$ meters.

I am unable to identify what's wrong with my thinking pattern.

**Mark scheme:**
[image: mark scheme]

Comment: You're given the velocity function, not the position function. As such, $v(0)=1$ represents the initial velocity: It does not tell you anything about the initial position. (Indeed, the initial position is not given and is irrelevant to solving the problem.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I realize my embarrassing mistake now,  v(0) = 1 representing the initial velocity. Regarding the actual initial position, I found out that at t=0 the displacement is 4.33. Then, when I integrate the second velocity equation and plug in s=4.33, I get t as 10.32 seconds.

Comment: To clarify, my own comment above doesn't indicate that I have solved the question. I am stuck at the same place.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call $x(t)$ to the particle position at time $t$. From the definition of velocity,
$$v(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\Longrightarrow\mathrm{d}x=v(t)\mathrm{d}t\Longrightarrow x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^tv(s)\mathrm{d}s\Longrightarrow x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^tv(s)\mathrm{d}s.$$

If $0\leq t\leq4$, the position is
\begin{align*}
x(t) & =x(0)+\int_0^t\bigl(5-(s-2)^2\bigr)\mathrm{d}s=x(0)+\int_0^t(-s^2+4s+1)\mathrm{d}s=\\
& =x(0)+\left[-\frac{s^3}{3}+2s^2+s\right]_0^t=x(0)-\frac{t^3}{3}+2t^2+t.
\end{align*}

And, if $t>4$,
\begin{align*}
x(t) & =x(0)+\int_0^4\bigl(5-(s-2)^2)\mathrm{d}s+\int_4^t\left(3-\frac{s}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}s=\\
& =x(0)-\frac{4^3}{3}+2\cdot4^2+4+\left[3s-\frac{s^2}{4}\right]_4^t=\\
& =x(0)+\frac{44}{3}+3t-\frac{t^2}{4}-\left(12-\frac{16}{4}\right)=\\
& =x(0)+\frac{t^2}{4}+3t+\frac{20}{3}.
\end{align*}

Now, let's see if the particle can get back to its initial position at $t\leq4$:
$$x(0)-\frac{t^3}{3}+2t^2+t=x(0)\Longrightarrow t\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}+2t+1\right)=0.$$
The solutions of the above equation are $t_1=0$, $t_2=2+\sqrt{6}>4$ and $t_3=2-\sqrt{6}<0$  and none of them is valid for this case.

So, now we look for $t>4$. We have
$$x(0)+\frac{t^2}{4}+3t+\frac{20}{3}=x(0)\Longrightarrow\frac{t^2}{4}+3t+\frac{20}{3}=0.$$
The solutions are
$$t_4=6-2\sqrt{\frac{47}{3}}<0,\quad t_5=6+2\sqrt{\frac{47}{3}}\approx13.9.$$
So $T=t_5\approx 13.9$.